# friendship and namespace issue

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm having troubles with friendship between a class of a namespace and a function as below:

How to tell that the friend function is outside of the namespace?

Thanks

```
namespace NS
{
    class Class
    {
    public:
        Class();
        virtual ~Class();

    private:
        void Foo();

        friend void Bar(Class&);
    };
}

void Bar(NS::Class& c)
{
    c.Foo();
}
```

Comment: Why do you make `Bar` `extern "C"`? It's not like it could be called from C code or other non-C++ code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Is that so? I thought simple class objects could be used as black-boxed struct object from within C?

Comment: Even if you get rid of the `extern "C"`, I can see the problem pops out only when you move `Bar` outside `NS`. And I think it's weird indeed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Oh nevermind, using a reference will be a bit hard in C..,

Comment: `NS::Class& c` in C ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the C thing. It was for C linkage but I don't need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the scope operator `::`

```
friend void ::Bar(Class&);
```

This tells the compiler that `Bar` is in the global scope.

---

Apparently the `Bar` function needs to be declared before it's used in the `friend` declaration when using the scope operator. The problem is that for `Bar` to be declared you need to declare both the namespace `NS` and the class `NS::Class`.

Something like this

```
namespace NS
{
    class Class;
}

extern "C"
{
    void Bar(NS::Class& c);
}

namespace NS
{
    class Class
    {
    public:
        Class();
        virtual ~Class();

    private:
        void Foo() {}

        friend void ::Bar(Class&);
    };
}

void Bar(NS::Class& c)
{
    c.Foo();
}
```

Comment: I thought so too, but this gave me " error: ‘void Bar(NS::Class&)’ should have been declared inside ‘::’".

Comment: @AmiTavory It turns out to be a little of a chicken-and-egg problem: `Bar` needs to be declared before the friend declaration, which of course needs both the `NS` namespace and the `NS::Class` class declarations to exist before the `Bar` declaration. I'll update the answer with working code.

Comment: No. A `friend`-declaration implicitly (forward) declares a symbol, if it hasn't been declared. You are missing the linkage specification.

Comment: @IInspectable Why is the linkage specification needed?